# Rooted Trees & Induction

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

So I am a little stumbled upon this question:

A full binary tree is a rooted tree where each leaf is at the same distance from the root and each internal node has exactly two children. Inductively, a full binary tree of depth 0 is the one node tree N, and a full binary tree of depth d+1 is a rooted tree whose two subtrees are each full binary trees of depth d. How many nodes and how many edges are in a full binary tree of depth d? Prove this answer by using the inductive defininition given in this problem.

Anything that could help me understand and get me started proving this would be awesome!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To get started, work out the answer for each $d\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ by hand. See if you can recognize a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full binary trees of depths $0,1$, and $2$ look like this:

```
           0               1                        2  
           *               +                        o  
                          / \                      / \  
                         *   *                    /   \  
                                                 +     +  
                                                / \   / \  
                                               *   * *   *
```

I’ve used different symbols for the nodes to make it easier to see how they are built up inductively: the tree of depth $1$ has a root `+` from which descend two copies of the tree of depth $0$, and the tree of depth $2$ has a root `o` from which descend two copies of the tree of depth $1$. Similarly, the full binary tree of depth $3$ has a root from which descend two copies of the full binary tree of depth $2$. If $f(n)$ is the number of nodes in the full binary tree of depth $n$, you can see that $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=3$, and $f(2)=7$, and from the description above it’s clear that $f(3)=2f(2)+1=2\cdot7+1=15$. At this point we have the following data:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&0&1&2&3\\
f(n):&1&3&7&15
\end{array}$$

It’s not hard to extend this table further: the inductive construction implies that $f(n+1)=2f(n)+1$ for each $n$, since we get the full binary tree of depth $n+1$ by putting two copies of the full binary tree of depth $n$ side by side and adding a root at the top.

You’re supposed to conjecture a closed formula for $f(n)$ and then prove it by induction on $n$. If you don’t immediately see a plausible formula, try extending the table a little further; the sequence of numbers $f(n)$ is very close to a sequence that ought to be pretty familiar.

Comment: Thanks fr the comment. We came up with the formula, f(d) = 2^(d+1) - 1 ... How do you show f(d+1) with induction assuming the formula @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @Stuart: Yes, that’s the right formula. The recursive definition of *full binary tree* immediately implies that $f(d)=2f(d-1)+1$ for all $d\ge 1$, since in the tree of depth $d$ you have two trees of depth $d-1$ and a root. You also know that $f(0)=1$. Let $g(d)=2^{d+1}-1$. Clearly $g(0)=1=f(0)$. Now show by induction on $d$ that your function $g$ satisfies the same recurrences as $f$: $g(d)=2g(d-1)+1$. Then you can say that since they agree at $d=0$ and grow by the same rule, they must be the same function: you’ve proved that $f=g$ and hence that $f(d)=2^{d+1}-1$ for all $d\ge 0$.